# Teams showing - Can't load the application on this page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-teams, typescript, pnpjs

I created a new application using SPFx in SharePoint online. I have sync the sppkg solution file to the Microsoft Teams.

But when I am adding the application in the teams Tab its showing an error:

> Cannot read the property 'id' of undefined

Below is the Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code? Show us the line of code where you are getting the undefined error.

Comment: hey i am new to SharePoint Spfx , please suggest me which part of code should i look to and this application is working on sharepoint online

Comment: Where are you seeing this error: "Cannot read the property 'id' of undefined"? in browser console?

Comment: I create a SPKG solution and upload it in AppCatalog in SharePoint Online >> sync to Teams >> Post that I open a teams channel and try to add this app from a Tab.  There it is showing me this error